# Вывод значения определенной ячейки mysql по id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Не могу разобраться как вывести нужную мне ячейку, например с id=1.
В интернете не нахожу похожих примеров.

Вот как у меня выводится сразу все ячейки столбца name:

```
$sql = db::q('SELECT * FROM '.$rows['table'].'');    
    if(db::n($sql) >= '1'){
     while ( $row = db::r($sql) ) {
 tpl::set ('{name}',$row[$rows['name']]);
}
```

(После чего если я вставлю штрихкод на сайте {name} там будут все имена)

Вопрос: Как мне вывести лишь name с id 1?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавить в запрос `where id = 1` ?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было описать row id и сделать запрос таким

```
$sql = db::q('SELECT * FROM '.$rows['stable'].' WHERE '.$rows["sID"].'=2');
```

Answer (score -1):

Какая версия php?
Если использовать mysqli тогда так

```
$mysqli =  new mysqli("host", "", "", "table_name");
$sql = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$rows['table'].' WHERE `id` = 1')
```

В даном случае тоже можно использовать условия WHERE (Где)

```
$sql = db::q('SELECT * FROM '.$rows['table'].' WHERE `id` = 1');
```

Comment: PHP Version 5.6.30

Comment: Возможно чем-то поможет. Пример использования WHERE в случае с такой структурой запросов: 

$sql = db::q('SELECT '.$rows['login'].','.$rows['admin'].','.$rows['online'].','.$rows['skin'].','.$rows['online'].' FROM '.$rows['table'].' WHERE '.$rows['admin'].'>0 order by '.$rows['admin'].' desc');

Comment: $sql = db::q('SELECT * FROM '.$rows['table'].' WHERE '.$rows['id'].' = 1');  работал з php 7, з 5 не знаком, по логике должно работать

Comment: Не нужно советовать уязвимые иньекцией запросы...